# Hamburger Menu Not showing text

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

```
 <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jerrica</a>
          <div class="container-fluid">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>


**CSS**

body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

nav{
background:black;
  height:10vh;

  /* Align logo in center */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}


a:link {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a {
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", "Verdana";
}
```

**My hamburger toggler bar is giving me problems because my text does not appear there. I believe that when I configured my toggler navigation bar's CSS, it obscured the content in my hamburger menu.**

Comment: For starters, you have closing `</li>` and `</ul>` tags that have no corresponding opening tags. And you never close your `<div class="navbar-nav">`.

Comment: Exactly as Marc mentioned you're missing about 3 closing's to `divs` and have the `</li>` and `</ul>` instead of them. However the important thing to mention is that you're using some kind of css not linked here and your issue is obviously css related meaning you most likely won't recieve any help

Answer (score 0):

Indent your code so you can easily check the blocks of code that you haven't closed properly.

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jerrica</a>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

When you do this you will notice that you have closing li and ul tags that don't have corresponding opening tags and that you are missing 3 div closing tags.

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fr4s9am/) you can check how your menu looks with all the blocks properly closed.